# Reuse wildcard match in bash

Tags: bash, wildcard

I want to do something like this in bash:

```
scp me@server:/data/stuff/*/needthis.txt ./?/needthis.txt
```

Where that ? in the command will be whatever was matched by the *.

My problem is there's a bunch of directories out of which I want to copy one file that's the same name in each directory, and I want to preserve the name of the directory they came from, but I don't just want to copy the entire "stuff" folder because there are other files in these directories that are hundreds of MB which I don't want to waste time downloading.

Can I do this easily?

Comment: As much as I imagine the answers work, I really thought there was a native way to do this in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `rsync` is what you need:

```
rsync -a --exclude='*' --include=needthis.txt me@server:/data/stuff/. .
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is very kludgy, and probably not efficient due to multiple invocation of scp:

```
ssh me@server 'find /data/stuff -name needthis.txt' 2>/dev/null | \
    while read src; do
        dest=.${src#/data/stuff}
        echo mkdir -p $(dirname $dest)
        echo scp "me@server:$src" "$dest"
    done
```

#### Explanation

1. The first line: you remote login into your server, and find all the interested files. The `2>/dev/null` phrase discards the extra output caused by the ssh command. The result of the first line is a list of file names, complete with full path, one file per line
2. The second line: the `while` statement reads each of these file into the variable `src`
3. The third line: constructs a destination file by discarding `/data/stuff` and replace it with a single dot (for the current directory).
4. The fourth and fifth lines: create a directory structure on the local machine that matches that of the source, then copy. However, the echo command prevents the actual execution. Instead, the commands themselves are displayed.

Now, run this rather long command and examine the output. Once you are satisfied, remove the two `echo` and run again--this time the executions will happen for real. I know this solution is long and kludgy, so I appreciate inputs from gurus out there.

Answer (score 1):

If the destination files all exist on the local machine, you can do:

```
for file in */needthis.txt; do
    scp me@server:/data/stuff/$file $file
done
```